# An ordered basis for a finite-dimensional $F$-vector space $V$ establishes a bijection between $V$ and $F^n$.

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, vector-spaces, solution-verification, proof-writing

> To summarize, each ordered basis of $V$ determines a one-one correspondence $\alpha \to (x_1,…,x_n)$ between the set of all vectors in $V$ and the set of all $n$-tuples in $F^n$.

**Question:** How to prove bijective map between $V$ and $F^n$ explicitly?

**My attempt:** $(V,F,+,\cdot)$ is finite dimensional vector space. Let $B=\{\alpha_1,…,\alpha_n\}$ be an ordered basis of $V$. $B=\{\alpha_1,…,\alpha_n\}$ is basis of $V$$\iff$$\forall \alpha \in V$, $\exists !x_\alpha =(x_{\alpha ,1},…,x_{\alpha ,n})\in F^n$ such that $\sum_{i\in J_n} x_{\alpha ,i}\cdot \alpha_i=\alpha$. So $f:V\to F^{n}$ defined by $f(\alpha)=x_\alpha = (x_{\alpha ,1},…,x_{\alpha ,n})$ is a well-defined map, i.e. $\forall \alpha \in V$, $\exists !x_\alpha \in F^n$ such that $f(\alpha)=x_\alpha$. Claim: $f$ is invertible, i.e. $\exists g:F^n \to V$ such that $g\circ f=\text{id}_V$ and $f\circ g=\text{id}_{F^n}$. Proof: We define $g:F^n \to V$ such that $g(y)=\sum_{i\in J_n}y_i \cdot \alpha_i$. Let $\alpha \in V$. Then $g\circ f(\alpha)=g(f(\alpha))=g(x_\alpha)$$= \sum_{i\in J_n} x_{\alpha ,i}\cdot \alpha_i=\alpha$. Thus $g\circ f=\text{id}_V$. Let $y=(y_1,…,y_n)\in F^{n}$. Then $f\circ g(y) =f(g(y))=f(\sum_{i\in J_n}y_i \cdot \alpha_i)$. Let $\sum_{i\in J_n}y_i \cdot \alpha_i =\beta \in V$. Since $\exists !x_\beta =(x_{\beta ,1},…,x_{\beta ,n})$ such that $\sum_{i\in J_n} x_{\beta ,i} \cdot \alpha_i =\beta$, we have $y=(y_1,…,y_n)=(x_{\beta ,1},…,x_{\beta ,n})=x_\beta$. So $f\circ g(y)=f(\sum_{i\in J_n}y_i \cdot \alpha_i)=f(\beta)=x_\beta=y$. Thus $f\circ g=\text{id}_{F^n}$. Hence $f$ is invertible, or, equivalently, bijective. **Is my proof correct?**

Comment: Your proof is hard to read. Use newlines to split the text.

Comment: Usually the curly brace notation $\{\ldots\}$ means an unordered set, so I wouldn't say $B = \{\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n\}$ is an ordered basis. I'd stick with the question's $(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n)$ notation for that. Of course, it is true (presumably by definition) that given an ordered basis $B = (\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n)$, the set of its vectors $\{\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n\}$ is a basis of the usual kind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternative : You can put your whole argument in the form :

$\dim(V) =n$ and let $\mathcal{B}=\{v_1,v_2,\ldots ,v_n\}$ basis for $V$.

$v\in V$ implies $v=\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{v,i}v_i$ where $x_{v,i}\in F$

Now define a map $f:V\to F^n$ by

$f(v) =(x_{v,1},x_{v,2}, \ldots ,x_{v,n})$

• Then $f$ is linear as for all $ v, u\in V$ and $\lambda\in F$ $\begin{align}f(v+\lambda u) &=(x_{v,1}+\lambda x_{u,1},x_{v,2}+\lambda x_{u,2}, \ldots +x_{v,n}+\lambda x_{u,n)}\\&=f(v)+\lambda f(u) \end{align}$

• $f$ is injective.

$\ker(f) =\{v\in V : f(v) =(0,0,\ldots, 0)\}$

Let $v\in \ker(f)$. Then $f(v) = (x_{v,1},x_{v,2}, \ldots ,x_{v,n}) =(0,0,\ldots ,0)$

Which implies $x_{v,i}=0 , \forall 1\le i\le n$. Thus $v=\sum_{i=1}^n x_{v,i}v_i=0$.

Hence $\ker(f) =\{\textbf{0}\}$

•$f$ is onto.

Since $f$ is a linear map between two same dimensional vector spaces, $f$ is injective iff $f$ is onto iff $f$ is bijective (consequence of Rank-nullity theorem)

Hence $f$ is an invertible linear map i.e an isomorphism.

---

**Note**: If you are not familiar with $\ker$ of a linear map,proof injectivity and surjectivity as the same way we do for any map between two sets.

•Injective

$f(v) =f(u) $ implies $(x_{v,1},x_{v,2}, \ldots ,x_{v,n})=(x_{u,1},x_{u,2}, \ldots ,x_{u,n})$

Then $x_{v,i}=x_{u,i}$ for all $1\le i\le n$.Hence $v=u$

•Surjective:

Given any $(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n) $ , consider $v=\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i v_i$ . Then $f(v) =(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n) $ .

Comment: The question has both the "solution-verification" tag and the bold question "**Is my proof correct?**", so a different proof is not an answer.

Comment: Thanks for downvoting. This should be an alternative proof written in more clear way.

Comment: @LostinSpace Thank you so much for the answer. I absolutely **love** alternative proof. I will read your post in half or one hour.

Comment: @LostinSpace I’m sorry for delay. Now I’m trying to solve a crazy problem using this(post) result. I’m stuck on one of the step. I wanna ask, is it true that any field have countable subfield?

Comment: Characteristics of a field either $0$ or a prime. It characteristics of a field is $0$ , then it contains the field of rational numbers $\Bbb{Q}$ and if characteristics of a field is prime say $p$ , then it contains the finite filed $\Bbb{Z}_p$. In both cases we have a countable subfield.

Comment: Ohhh! $\ker(f)$ is same as null space of $f$, I use $N_f$notation for null space of $f$. I know the result: let $f$ be a linear map. Then $f$ is injective iff $\ker(f)=\{0_V\}$. I have seen rank nullity theorem but haven’t proved it yet, mainly because I’m trying to prove dim$(N_T)+$dim$(R_T)=$dim$(V)$ result on my own. Just a nit pick, it’s essential to show $f$ is a well defined map. Your last proof of surjective, also requires uniqueness part. $v=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i v_i$ $\Rightarrow$ $(x_1,…,x_n)=(x_{v,1},…,x_{v,n})=x_v$. Thus $f(v)=x_v=(x_1,…,x_n)$. And your note part should be approach 2.

Comment: Well definedness, uniqueness all follows from the properties of basis. Every vector is a combination of basis vectors( as spanning set) and the coefficients of the combination is unique ( as linearly independent).

Answer (score 2):

Your proof is overall correct. However, you can enhance it by

1. From the form standpoint, separate topics in lines with headers. As currently written, it is hard to read.
2. From the substance, you're missing the point that $f$ is in fact a linear map as $\mathbb F^n$ is a linear space. From this, you can study bijectivity by looking at the kernel as we're dealing with finite-dimensional linear spaces.

Comment: I’m sorry for messy proof. If you can edit my proof that would be great. Unfortunately, I don’t know definitions of linear space and kernel. Maybe it will come later in book.

Comment: @user264745 Linear space is just another word for vector space. Do you know the definition of a linear map?

Comment: Yes. I known definition of linear map/transformation.

Answer (score 0):

We can use this result to prove $V$ is isomorphic to $F^n$. Which is precisely theorem 10 section 3.3. **Proof:** By theorem 7 section 3.2, it is suffice to show, either $f$ or $g$ is a linear map. I will show both $f$ and $g$ are linear map. Let $c\in F$ and $\alpha, \beta\in V$. Then $\exists !x_\alpha =(x_{\alpha ,1},…,x_{\alpha ,n})\in F^n$ such that $\sum_{i\in J_n} x_{\alpha ,i}\cdot \alpha_i=\alpha$ and $\exists !x_\beta =(x_{\beta ,1},…,x_{\beta ,n})\in F^n$ such that $\sum_{i\in J_n} x_{\beta ,i}\cdot \alpha_i=\beta$. So $c\cdot \alpha +\beta$ $=c\cdot (\sum_{i\in J_n} x_{\alpha ,i} \cdot \alpha_i)$ $+ \sum_{i\in J_n} x_{\beta ,i}\cdot \alpha_i$. By distributive axiom of vector space, $c\cdot (\sum_{i\in J_n} x_{\alpha ,i} \cdot \alpha_i)$ $+ \sum_{i\in J_n} x_{\beta ,i}\cdot \alpha_i$ $= \sum_{i\in J_n} (c\cdot x_{\alpha ,i}+x_{\beta ,i})\cdot \alpha_i$. By uniqueness, $c \cdot x_{\alpha ,i}+x_{\beta ,i}=x_{c\cdot \alpha+\beta, i}$, $\forall i\in J_n$. Thus $f(c\cdot \alpha +\beta)=x_{c\cdot \alpha +\beta}$ $=(c\cdot x_{\alpha ,1}+x_{\beta ,1},…, c\cdot x_{\alpha ,n}+x_{\beta ,n})$ $=c\cdot f(\alpha)+f(\beta)$. Hence $f$ is a linear map. Let $c\in F$ and $x,y\in F^n$. Then $x=(x_1,…,x_n)$ and $y=(y_1,…,y_n)$. So $c\cdot x+y$ $=(c\cdot x_1+y_1,…,c\cdot x_n+y_n)$. So $g(c\cdot x+y)$ $= \sum_{i\in J_n} (c\cdot x_{i} +y_{i})\cdot \alpha_i$. By distributive axiom of vector space, $\sum_{i\in J_n} (c\cdot x_{i} +y_{i})\cdot \alpha_i$ $=c\cdot (\sum_{i\in J_n} x_{i}\cdot \alpha_i)$ $+ \sum_{i\in J_n} y_{i}\cdot \alpha_i$ $= c\cdot g(x)+g(y)$. Thus $g(c\cdot x+y)= c\cdot g(x)+g(y)$. Hence $g$ is a linear map.