# Exercise 14, Section 2.3 of Hoffman’s Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification, proof-writing

> Let $V$ be the set of real numbers. Regard $V$ as a vector space over the field of rational numbers, with the usual operations. Prove that this vector space is not finite dimensional.

We can prove a stronger result:

> Let $(V,F,+,\cdot)$ be a vector space over field $F$.  If $V$ is uncountable and $F$ is countable, then $(V,F,+,\cdot)$ is infinite dimensional vector space.

**My attempt:** Assume towards contradiction, $V$ is finite-dimensional vector space, $\mathrm{dim}(V)=n\in \Bbb{N}$. Let $B=\{\alpha_1,…,\alpha_n\}$ is basis of $V$. Then $\exists f:V \to F^n$ such that $f$ is bijective, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4486838/861687) is the proof. Since $f$ is bijective, $|V|=|F^n|$. Since $V$ is uncountable, $F^n$ is uncountable. But by theorem 2.13 of Baby Rudin, $F^n$ is countable. Thus we reach contradiction. Hence $(V, F,+,\cdot)$ is infinite dimensional vector space. **Is my proof correct?**

Comment: I think your proof is correct :/

Comment: Yes, your proof is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative:

---

---

Suppose $\dim(V) =n$  and $\{1,\pi,\pi^2,\ldots ,\pi^n\}$ is a set of $n+1$ vectors, hence dependent.

Then $\sum_{k=0}^{n} r_k\pi^k=0$ where $r_k\in \Bbb{Q}$ and not all $r_k$ zero. $(r_1\neq 0) $

Hence $\pi$ is a root of the polynomial $f(x) \in \Bbb{Q}[x]$ , $f(x) =\sum_{k=0}^{n} r_k x^k$

implies $\pi$ is algebraic which is a contradiction.

Existence of transcendental number forces $\dim(V) $ infinite.

Comment: Proving the existence of transcendental numbers is in my opinion more difficult than proving what we want to prove (but essentially done the same way, through a counting argument). So I don't think this is the intended solution.

Comment: Damm… that is an awesome proof! We proved about dimension using properties of space $\Bbb{R}$. To be honest, I don’t exactly know the notation $\Bbb{Q}[x]$. Some linear algebra book say it is polynomial with rational coefficient and some say it is function. I think $\Bbb{F}[x]$ denotes $\{\sum_{k=0}^n r_k x^k| n\in \Bbb{N} \cup \{0\}, r_k\in F, x\in F\}$. I have googled definition of algebraic and transcendental numbers. Is there elementary proof of $\pi$ is transcendental? And I guess we have to separate case for $n=0$ and $n\in \Bbb{N}$. Because for $n=0$ we can’t use algebraic argument.

Comment: @Arthur you’re right. But I’m taking $\pi$ is transcendental for granted.

Comment: $f(x)\in \Bbb{Q}[x]$ means $f(x) $ is a polynomial with rational coefficients.

Comment: @Arthur The set of algebraic numbers is countable  implies there is at least one (infact infinitely many) transcendental numbers. Hence instead of working with $\pi$ , we can choose any transcendental number whose existence is proved by Cardinality agrument. Then there shouldn't be any problem about the non constructive proof. Isn't it?

Comment: And what’s your opinion on separate case for $n=0$ and $n\geq 1$. Am I right?

Comment: @LostinSpace ohh! Yes I think that would work. Set of all algebraic numbers is countable is actually exercise 2 chapter 2 of Baby Rudin.

Comment: @LostinSpace Why go through all that trouble when an almost identical counting argument as your comment is what's needed to solve this problem directly, without the need for a secondary argument as given in your answer post? _That's_ my point. Why prove uncountably many transcendentals (as a lemma), when the existence of uncountably many irrationals gives you the infinite linearly independent set we are actually after by a simpler argument?