# Theorem 11, Section 3.4 of Hoffman’s Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, proof-writing, linear-transformations

> Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space over the field $F$ and $W$ be an $m$-dimensional vector space over the field $F$. Let $B=\{\alpha_1,…\alpha_n\}$ and $B’=\{\beta_1,…,\beta_m\}$ be ordered basis of $V$ and $W$, respectively. $\forall T\in L(V,W)$, $\exists A\in M_{m\times n}(F)$ such that $[T(\alpha)]_{B’}=A\cdot [\alpha]_B$, for all $\alpha \in V$. Furthermore, $f:L(V,W)\to M_{m\times n}(F)$ defined by $f(T)=A=[T]_{B}^{B’}$ is bijective map.

**My attempt:** First we need to check $f$ is a well-defined function, i.e. $\forall T\in L(V,W)$, $\exists !$ $A\in M_{m\times n}(F)$ such that $f(T)=A$. Let $C=(C_{ij})\in M_{m\times n}(F)$ such that $[T(\alpha)]_{B’}=C\cdot [\alpha]_B$. By uniqueness of coordinates matrix of $T(\alpha)$ relative to ordered basis $B’$, $\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}x_j$ $=\sum_{j=1}^n C_{ij}x_j$, for all $i\in J_m$, where $(x_1,…,x_n)\in F^n$ is coordinate of $\alpha$ relative to ordered basis $B$. **How to show $A_{ij}=C_{ij}$, $\forall (i,j)\in J_m\times J_n$?**

There are two ways to show $f$ is bijective, $(1)$ $f$ is injective and surjective, $(2)$ $f$ is invertible, i.e. $\exists g:M_{m\times n}(F) \to L(V,W)$ such that $g\circ f=\text{id}_{L(V,W)}$ and $f\circ g=\text{id}_{M_{m\times n}(F)}$.

Proof using $(1)$. **Approach(1):** If $f(T)=f(U)$, for some $T,U\in L(V,W)$. So $f(T)=f(U)$ $=[T]_{B}^{B’}=[U]_{B}^{B’}$. It’s easy to check $T=U$, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4493987/861687) is proof. Hence $f$ is injective. Let $A=(A_{ij})\in M_{m\times n}$. Define $\gamma_j =\sum_{i=1}^m A_{ij}\cdot_W \beta_i$, for all $j\in J_n$. By theorem 1 section 3.1, $\exists !$ $T\in L(V,W)$ such that $T(\alpha_j)=\gamma_j= \sum_{i=1}^m A_{ij}\cdot_W \beta_i $, for all $j\in J_n$. By uniqueness of coordinates matrix of $T(\alpha_j)$ relative to ordered basis $B’$, $A_j=[T(\alpha_j)]_{B’}$, $\forall j\in J_n$. Thus $f(T)=[T]_{B}^{B’}$ $=([T(\alpha_1)]_{B’}\dotsb [T(\alpha_n)]_{B’})$ $=(A_1\dotsb A_n)=A$. Hence $f$ is surjective. So $f$ is bijective. Actually in proof of surjectivity, we showed $\forall A\in M_{m\times n}(F)$, $\exists !$ $T\in L(V,W)$ such that $f(T)=A$. Which is precisely the definition of bijective map. **Approach(2):** $V, W$ are $m,n$-dimensional vector space over field $F$, respectively. By theorem 5 section 3.2, $\mathrm{dim}(L(V,W))=mn$. By exercise 12 section 2.3, $\mathrm{dim}(M_{m\times n}(F))=mn$. So $\mathrm{dim}(V,W)= \mathrm{dim}(M_{m\times n}(F))$. If $f(T)=f(U)$, for some $T,U\in L(V,W)$. So $f(T)=f(U)$ $=[T]_{B}^{B’}=[U]_{B}^{B’}$. It’s easy to check $T=U$, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4493987/861687) is proof. Hence $f$ is injective. By [theorem 9 section 3.2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4489586/861687), $f$ is bijective.

Proof using $(2)$. In proof of $f$ is surjective, we showed $\forall A\in M_{m\times n}(F)$, $\exists !$ $T\in L(V,W)$ such that $f(T)=[T]_{B}^{B’}=A$. Define $g:M_{m\times n}(F)\to L(V,W)$ such that $g(A)=T$. So $g$ is a well-defined function. Let $T\in L(V,W)$. Then $g\circ f(T)$ $=g(f(T))$ $=g(A)=T$. Thus $g\circ f(T)=T$, $\forall T\in L(V,W)$. Hence $g\circ f=\text{id}_{L(V,W)}$. Let $A\in M_{m\times n}(F)$. Then $f\circ g(A)$ $=f(g(A))$ $=f(T)=A$. Thus $f\circ g(A)=A$, $\forall A\in M_{m\times m}(F)$. Hence $f\circ g=\text{id}_{M_{m\times n}(F)}$. **Is my proof correct?** IMO, this proof is extremely “artificial” since I use $f$ is bijective to prove $f$ is bijective.

Hoffman’s prove existence of inverse map $g$ in following way:
Let $A=(A_{ij})\in M_{m\times n}(F)$. Define $T:V\to W$ such that $T(\alpha)$ $=T(\sum_{j=1}^nx_j \cdot_V \alpha_j)$ $=\sum_{i=1}^m (\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}x_j) \cdot \beta_i$, for all $\alpha \in V$. It’s easy to check, $T$ is a linear map and matrix of $T$ relative to ordered bases $B,B’$ is $A$. So $T\in L(V,W)$ and $f(T)=[T]_{B}^{B’}=A$. By theorem 1 section 3.1, $T$ is unique.

**Edit:**

> **Claim:** $\forall T\in L(V,W)$, $\exists!$ $A=[T]_B^{B’}\in M_{m\times n}(F)$ such that $[T(\alpha)]_{B’}=A\cdot [\alpha]_B$, for all $\alpha \in V$.

**Proof:** Let $T\in L(V,W)$. Then $[T]_{B}^{B’}$ $=([T(\alpha_i)]_{B’}\dotsb [T(\alpha_n)]_{B’})\in M_{m\times n}(F)$ is matrix of $T$ relative to ordered basis $B,B’$. It’s easy to check, $[T(\alpha)]_{B’}=[T]_B^{B’} \cdot [\alpha]_B$, for all $\alpha \in V$. Now we show $A=(A_{ij})=[T]_{B}^{B’}$ is unique. Let $C=(C_{ij})\in M_{m\times n}(F)$ such that $[T(\alpha)]_{B’}=C\cdot [\alpha]_B$, for all $\alpha \in V$. In particular, $[T(\alpha_j)]_{B’}=C\cdot [\alpha_j]_B$, $\forall j \in J_n$. Fix $j\in J_n$. Note $[\alpha_j]_B=e_j$ $=(x_1,….x_n)$, where $x_i=0_F$, $\forall i\in J_n\setminus \{j\}$ and $x_j=1_F$. By uniqueness of coordinates matrix of $T(\alpha_j)$ relative to ordered basis $B’$, we have $\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}x_j$ $=\sum_{j=1}^n C_{ij}x_j$ $=A_{ij}$ $=C_{ij}$, for all $i\in J_m$. Since $j$ was arbitrary, $A_{ij}=C_{ij}$, $\forall j\in J_n$. Thus $A_{ij}=C_{ij}$, $\forall (i,j)\in J_m\times J_n$. Hence $A=[T]_B^{B’}=C$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$V, W$ be two finite dimensional vector space over $F$ of dimension $n, m$ respectively. Let us fix a pair of basis $(\beta, \beta') $.

Given a matrix $A\in M_{m×n}(F) $ , consider the associated linear map $L_A:V\to W$ defined by $$L_A(x) =Ax$$

Check :

1. $L_A$ indeed a linear map.
2. $[L]_{\beta}^{\beta'}=A$
3. For a fixed pair of basis $(\beta, \beta') $ , $L_A$ is unique.

(Hint: A. Linear map is completely determined by the action on the Basis)

4. $L_{A+B}= L_A +L_B$
5. $L_{cA}=cL_A$ for $c\in F$

---

Claim: Two vector spaces $M_{m×n}(F) $ and $\mathcal{L}(V, W) $ are isomorphic i.e there is an invertible linear map between those two spaces.

Proof: Let us consider a map $L : M_{m×n}(F)\to \mathcal{L}(V, W) $ defined by $$L(A) =L_A$$

• Then this map is well defined by $3$.

• $L$ is a linear map by $4$ and $5$.

$\begin{align}\ker L&=\{A\in M_{m×n}(F): L(A) =0\}\\&=\{A\in M_{m×n}(F): L_A=0\}\\&=\{\textbf{0}\} \end{align}$

$L$ is also surjective as every operator in $\mathcal{L}(V, W) $ has a matrix representation w.r.to $(\beta, \beta') $

---

---

The inverse map $L^{-1}:=\varphi:\mathcal{L}(V, W) \to 
 M_{m×n}(F)$
defined by $\varphi(T) =[T]_{\beta}^{\beta'}$ is also an isomorphism.

You can check it directly now.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I will check all 5 properties of map $L_A$. I’m wondering what $Ax$ is? Because $A$ is a matrix and $x \in V$. Particularly, I really want to prove uniqueness of matrix (first paragraph of my attempt). I’m stuck on that problem for long time. $L^{-1}=\varphi$ defined by $\varphi (T)=[T]_B^{B’}$ is linear immediately by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4493987/861687) result.

Comment: $Ax$ matrix -vector multiplication. Check it.  It is often easy to work with linear map rather than matrix.

Comment: This is my first time seeing matrix vector multiplication. I googled it. There is no Wikipedia page on that topic. Can you provide some references link? I’m sorry to asking you again, **How to show $\forall T\in L(V,W)$, $\exists !$ $A\in M_{m\times n}(F)$ such that $[T(\alpha)]_{B’}=A\cdot [\alpha]_B$, for all $\alpha \in V$?**

Comment: See the book of Serge Lang.  Matrix of a linear map and Linear map of a matrix. For matrix multiplication you can see book by Gilbert strang.

Comment: For a fixed pair of basis there exists a unique matrix associated to a linear map.

Comment: Fix a pair of basis $B, B'$. Then matrix of $T$  is obtained by expressing image of the basis vector of $B$ as a linear combination of the basis vectors of $B'$ . Then putting the coordinate into columns. Coordinate of a vector is unique .

Comment: $B=\{u_1, u_2\}$ , $B'=\{v_1, v_2\}$ . Then $T(u_1) = c_{11}v_1+c_{21}v_2$ . Then $(c_{11}, c_{21}) $  is unique. Similarly $T(u_2) =c_{12}v_1+c_{22}v_2$ . Then $[T]=\begin{pmatrix} c_{11}&c_{12}\\c_{21}&c_{22}\end{pmatrix}$ .

Comment: Fixed basis implies unique matrix

Comment: You showed existence of matrix associated to a linear map. To show uniqueness we have to do following: Let $C=(C_{ij})\in M_{m\times n}(F)$ such that $[T(\alpha)]_{B’}=C\cdot [\alpha]_B$, $\forall \alpha \in V$. By uniqueness of coordinates matrix of $T(\alpha)$ relative to ordered basis $B’$, $\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}x_j$ $=\sum_{j=1}^n C_{ij}x_j$, for all $i\in J_m$, where $(x_1,…,x_n)\in F^n$ is coordinate of $\alpha$ relative to ordered basis $B$. **How to show $A_{ij}=C_{ij}$, $\forall (i,j)\in J_m\times J_n$?**

Comment: Fact: A vector is a unique linear combination of basis vectors. Show the coefficients $A_{ij}$ , $B_{ij}$ are equal.

Comment: Consider my above example. Suppose there is another matrix $[T]_{B}^{B'}=D=\begin{pmatrix}d_{11}&d_{12}\\d_{21}&d_{22}\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Then $T(u_1) =d_{11}v_1+d_{21}v_2$ and $T(u_2) =d_{12}v_1+d_{22}v_2$ and in the first matrix we have seen $T(u_1) =c_{11}v_1+c_{21}v_2$ and $T(u_2) =c_{12}v_1+c_{22}v_2$

Comment: $T(u_1) \in W $ has a unique representation as a combination of basis vectors $v_1, v_2$ . Hence $(d_{11},d_{21})=(c_{11},c_{21})$

Comment: Ahhhh….!!! I think I found the solution to my problem. Rather than working with arbitrary $\alpha \in V$. I should work on $B=\{\alpha_1,…,\alpha_n\}$. To be precise, $[T(\alpha_k)]_{B’} =C\cdot [\alpha_k]_B$, $\forall k\in J_n$. Fix $k\in J_n$. Then $[\alpha_k]_B=e_k$. By uniqueness of coordinates matrix of $T(\alpha_k)$ relative to ordered basis $B’$, $A_{ik}=C_{ik}$, $\forall i\in J_m$. Since $k$ was arbitrary, $A_{ik}=C_{ik}$, $\forall k\in J_n$. Hence $A=C=(A_{ij})=(C_{ij})$. Our desired result!

Comment: The problem in your proof is that you’re implicitly assuming $A=[T]_B^{B’}=D$. That means you’re using the theorem to prove theorem.

Comment: Exactly. That's the way we find matrix of a linear map. We take a basis vector from domain space and the we write it as linear combination of the basis vectors of the target space. The coefficients of that combination is a column of the matrix.

Comment: My strategy : Suppose $T$ has  two matrix w.r.to same pair of basis.Then i have shown those two matrices can be different in  the above example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137865/discussion-between-user264745-and-lost-in-space).

Comment: To show $L(V,W)\cong M_{m\times n}(F)$, we don’t have to anything, just notice $\mathrm{dim}(L(V,W))= \mathrm{dim}(M_{m\times n}(F)=mn$. By [exercise 6 section 3.3](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4495964/861687), $L(V,W)\cong M_{m\times n}(F)$. We are done!

Comment: Yes. Two same finite dimensional vector spaces over same base field are isomorphic.

Comment: Have you seen this post https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4497833/977780

Comment: Yes and I tryed to that problem by my own. After unsuccessful attempt, I saw hint. With help of hint, I solved it. I haven’t seen your complete proof but it looks like new approach. Btw I saw that problem via your post.