# Exercise 6, Section 3.3 of Hoffman’s Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, proof-writing, alternative-proof, vector-space-isomorphism

> Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over field $F$, with $\mathrm{dim}(V)=n\in \Bbb{N}$. Then $V\cong W$$\iff$ $\mathrm{dim}(V)=\mathrm{dim}(W)$.

**My attempt:** $(\Leftarrow)$ Suppose $\mathrm{dim}(V)=\mathrm{dim}(W)$. **Approach(1):** Since $\mathrm{dim}(V)=\mathrm{dim}(W)=n$, we have $V\cong F^n$ and $W\cong F^n$, by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4486838/861687) result. It’s easy to check $($class of vector space $,\cong )$ is an equivalence relation. By symmetry property, $W\cong F^n$ $\Rightarrow$  $F^{n}\cong W$. By transitive property, $V\cong F^n$ and $F^n\cong W$  $\Rightarrow$ $V\cong W$. Hence $V\cong W$. **Approach(2):** Since $\mathrm{dim}(V)=\mathrm{dim}(W)=n$, we have $\exists B_V=\{\alpha_1,…\alpha_n\}$ basis of $V$, $\exists B_W=\{\beta_1,…,\beta_n\}$ basis of $W$. By theorem 1 section 3.1, $\exists!$ $T\in L(V,W)$ such that $T(\alpha_j)=\beta_j$, $\forall j\in J_n$. So $\{T(\alpha_1),…,T(\alpha_n)\}$ $=\{\beta_1,…,\beta_n\}$ is basis of $W$. By [theorem 9 section 3.2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4489586/861687), $T$ is bijective. Thus $T$ is isomorphism. Hence $V\cong W$.

$(\Rightarrow)$ Suppose $V\cong W$. Then $\exists T\in L(V,W)$ such that $T$ is bijective. So $N_T=\{0_V\}$ and $R_T=W$. By rank nullity theorem, $\mathrm{dim}(V)$ $= \mathrm{dim}(N_T)+ \mathrm{dim}(R_T)$ $= \mathrm{dim}(W)$. Hence $\mathrm{dim}(V)= \mathrm{dim}(W)$. **Is my proof correct?**

In proof of $(\Rightarrow)$, we implicitly use $T$ is a linear map, because without linear condition we can’t conclude $N_T=\{0_V\}$. **Am I right?**

Comment: For (⇒), the linear map in question is definitely not unique. Otherwise, looks kosher to me.

Comment: @ElchananSolomon yes. You’re right. It was a typo, my bad.

Comment: Your proof is perfect.                       
  $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space over $F$ then $V\cong F^{\dim V}$

"Being isomorphic " is an equivalence relation. 

 $W\cong F^{\dim W}$



Then $V\cong W\iff F^{\dim V}\cong F^{\dim W}\iff \dim V=\dim W$

Whole task reduces to show $F^m\cong F^n \iff m=n$

Comment: @LostinSpace Yup. That is a nice result to keep in mind.

Comment: If $b_1α_1 +b_2α_2 +b_3α_3 = 0$ , then by L.I of $\{\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3\}$ implies $b_1=b_2=b_3=0$ but you assume $b_1, b_2, b_3$ not all zero. In other words only combination of $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3$ that can produce the zero vector is the trivial combination (all coefficients are $0$)

Comment: @LostinSpace I’m so stupid……. Thank you so much for the reply.

Comment: It's a process of learning. Don't need to feel sorry. You are  hardworking.

Comment: Ok. No problem.