# Exercise 13, Section 2.C - Linear Algebra Done Right.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification

Exercise: Suppose $U$ and $W$ are both $4$-dimensional subspaces of $C^6$. Prove that
there exist two vectors in $U \cap W$ such that neither of these vectors is a
scalar multiple of the other.

My attempt at a proof is as follows.

Proof: Let $u_1,. . .,u_4$ be a basis of $U$ and let $w_1,. . .,w_4$ be a basis of $W$. Then, $u_1,. . .,u_4,w_1,. . .,w_4$ spans $U+W$. Because $U+W$ is a subspace of $C^6$, the $\dim(U+W)\le 6$. Thus, $u_1,. . .,u_4,w_1,. . .,w_4$ can be reduced to a basis of $U+W$. In the process, none of the $u's$ get removed as $u_1,. . .,u_4$ is linearly independent. Thus, some of the $w's$ get removed in the process. Because $\dim(U+W)\le 6$, at least two of the $w's$ get removed. These are the $w's\in U\cap W$. Because $w_1, . .,w_4$ is linearly independent, none of these two vectors are a scalar multiple of each other.

Is the proof correct?

Edit: I implicitly use that theorem that every spanning list in a vector space can be reduced to a basis of that vector space. In the process, we remove those vectors that are in the span of the previous ones. Thus, if we have the list $v_1,. . .,v_k$. We remove $v_j$ only if $v_j$ is in the span of $v_1,. . .,v_{j-1}$.

Edit 2: I have come to know that the proof is wrong. For future readers, I am writing another proof that is also suggested as a hint in the answers.

Proof 2: Using the formula $\dim (U+W)=\dim(U)+\dim(W)-\dim(U\cap W)$, we see that $\dim(U\cap W) \ge 2$. This is because  $\dim(C^6)=6$ and $U+W$ is a subspace of $C^6$. Thus, $\dim(U+W)\le 6$. Let $j\in Z^+$ with $2\le j\le 6$. Let $\dim(U\cap W)=j$. Let $v_1,. . .,v_j$ be a basis of $U\cap W$. Then we have that $v_1,v_2\in U\cap W$ are not scalar multiples of each other as they are linearly independent. Completing the proof.

Comment: Why are the removed $w$'s in $U$?

Comment: @Cpc because these $w’s$ can’t be written as a linear combination of $w_1,. . .,w_4$. They can only be written as a linear combination of the basis of $U$.

Comment: @Cpc I should add more. I was using a theorem proved previously. That every spanning list can be reduced to a basis. In that process we remove those vectors that are in the span of the previous ones. This is the reason the $w’s \in U$

Comment: Oh yeah,  that works. You might want to mention it though.   Good job.

Comment: Technically, reducing $u_1,...,w_4$ does not come with an ordering, albeit the 'natural' order would imply what you have written above. I might invoke Gram Schmidt if I was feeling sufficiently motivated.

Comment: @copper.hat I’m not sure if I understand your comment. If not let me know. But in the book, a list is by definition ordered.

Comment: @copper.hat it’s essentially defined analogous to a finite ordered set without the whole set theory notation or operations.

Comment: When you write that none of the $u_k$ get removed, you are presuming (not unreasonably) that the reduction is performed in a specific order, my point would be to make that order explicit.

Comment: @copper.hat yes I do. As I said on your answer, that we remove those that are in the span of the previous vectors. Thus, if we have the list $v_1,. . .,v_k$, we remove $v_k$ only if $v_k$ is in the span of $v_1,. . .,v_{k-1}$. I should add this to the post.

Comment: The correct answer to this depends on the tools available in the book I suppose, so I'm not sure what answer to upvote. The result is fairly basic so there are lots of different ways to do this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by $w'$ you mean some of the $w_1, \dots, w_4$, then no, your proof is not correct. Those of $w_1, \dots, w_4$ which you remove do not have to lie in $U$. It's easy to construct an example where none of $w_1, \dots, w_4$ lie in $U$. For example, let $e_1, \dots, e_6$ be a basis of $\mathbb{C}^6$;
$u_i=e_i$ for $i=1,\dots, 4$; $w_1 = e_5$; $w_2=e_6$; $w_3=e_1+e_5$; $w_4=e_2+e_6$.

Comment: I was using a theorem proved earlier that a spanning list can be reduced to a basis. Because the spanning list of $U+W$ was of length 8 and $\dim(U+W) \le 6$, we know that list is not a basis of $U+W$. And because there is a list of length 6 or less that does span $U+W$, we know that we can’t have a linearly independent list longer than length 6. Thus, some of the $w’s$ are indeed in $U$ Because $w_1,. . .,w_4$ is linearly independent as it’s a basis of $W$. We remove those vectors that are in the span of the previous ones.

Comment: @Seeker What exactly do you mean by $w'$s? What are they in my example?

Comment: Sone of the vectors from $w_1,. . .w_4$.

Comment: @Seeker So in my example that would be $w_3$ and $w_4$, right? They do not lie in $U$. For example, $w_3$ does lie in the span of the previous vectors — i. e., $u_1, u_2, u_3, u_4, w_1, w_2$; but it does not lie in the span of $u_1, u_2, u_3, u_4$.

Comment: Yes, that is a counterexample. Thanks a lot for answering!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**
It suffices to prove $U\cap W$ has dimension at least $2$.

Use $$\dim (U+W)=\dim U+\dim W-\dim (U\cap W)$$.

Answer (score 2):

Define $T:U×W\to \Bbb{C^6}$ by $$T(u, w) =u+w$$

Then

1. $T$ is a linear map.
2. $\ker T=U\cap W$
3. $\operatorname{Im} T=U+V$
4. $\dim \operatorname{Im} T\le \dim \Bbb{C}^6=6$

Now $\begin{align}\dim (\ker T) &=\dim(U×W) -\dim \operatorname{Im} T\\&=\dim U+\dim W -\dim \operatorname{Im} T\\&\ge 4+4-6\\&\ge 2\end{align}$

Hence $\dim(U\cap V) \ge 2$ . Now you can choose two linearly vectors from $U\cap W$ .

Note:

$U×W$ is a vector space of $\dim U+\dim W$ . Because $\{(u_1,0),(u_2,0),\ldots ,(u_m, 0),(0,w_1),(0,w_2),\ldots,(0,w_n)\}$

is a basis of $U×W$ where $\{u_1, u_2, \ldots, u_m\}$ and $\{(v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_n\}$ are basis of $U$ and $W$ respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Because $4\le \dim(U+W)\le 6$, and $\dim(U\cap W)=\dim(U)+\dim(W)-\dim(U+W)$ it is implied that $$2\le \dim(U\cap W)\le 4,$$ which suggests that the subspace is neither zero-space $\{0\}$ nor a line of dimension $1$. So, you can always choose two linearly independent vectors $u$ and $v$ in $U\cap W$ such that $u\ne kv$.

Answer (score 0):

> Thus, u1,...,u4,w1,...,w4 can be reduced to a basis of U+W. In the process, none of the u′s get removed as u1,...,u4 is linearly independent. Thus, some of the w′s get removed in the process.

That seems problematic to me. Reduction of a linearly dependent set of vectors to a linearly independent one is not in general a unique process; there are many different combinations of vectors you can remove to achieve independence. The fact that the u's are independent suggests that there *exists* a process that doesn't remove them, but your wording implies that *no* process removes them, which is not correct. I'm also not sure your instructor would consider it trivial that once one w is removed, the set is still linearly dependent.

I think a better approach is to first prove that there are non-zero vectors in U∩W, then pick one, then take the subset of U that is perpendicular to that vector, and the subset of W perpendicular to the vector, and then show that the intersection of those two subsets has a nonzero vector.

Comment: There was a theorem proved earlier that every spanning list can be reduced down to a basis of the vector space. In that we remove those vectors that are in the span of the previous ones. I should have added that to the proof to make it clear. My bad on that one.

Answer (score 0):

Define $A: U \times W \to \mathbb{C}^6$ by $A(u,w) = u+w$. Since $\dim {\cal R} A \le 6$, we have $\dim \ker A \ge 2$. In particular, there are linearly independent $(u_1,w_1), (u_2,w_2)$ in $\ker A$.Since they are in the kernel, we see that $w_1=-u_1, w_2 = -u_2 \in U \cap W$ and linear independence implies that $(u_1,-u_1), (u_2,-u_2)$ are not scalar multiples of each other.