# Theorem 15, Section 3.5 of Hoffman’s Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, proof-writing, alternative-proof, dual-spaces

**Definition:** Let $(V,F,+_V,\cdot_V)$ and $(F,F,+_F,\cdot_F)$ be vector space over field $F$. Then $V^*=(L(V,F),F,+_L,\cdot_L)$ is called **dual space** of $V$.

---

Let $B=\{\alpha_1,…,\alpha_n\}$ be basis of $V$. By theorem 1 section 3.1, $\forall i\in J_n$, $\exists !f_i\in L(V,F)$ such that $f_i(\alpha_j)=\delta_{ij}$, $\forall j\in J_n$. We can actually write $f_i$ explicitly. Let $h:V\to F^n$ be an isomorphism map ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4486838/861687) is proof) and $\pi_i:F^n\to F$ be a projection map. Then $\pi_i\circ h:V\to F$ satisfy our desired property, $\pi_i\circ h(\alpha_j)$ $=\pi_{i}(h(\alpha_j))$ $=\pi_{i}(e_j)$ $=\delta_{ij}$, $\forall j\in J_n$. By uniqueness, $f_i=\pi_i \circ h$. Now we’re ready to solve theorem 15 section 3.5.

> Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over the field $F$, and let $B= \{\alpha_1,…, \alpha_n\}$ be a basis for $V$. Then there is a unique dual basis $B^* = \{f_1,,…, f_n\}$ for $V^*$ such that $f_i(a_j) = \delta_{ij}$. For each linear functional $f$ on $V$ we have $f=\sum_{i=1}^nf(\alpha_i)\cdot_Lf_i$ and for each vector $\alpha$ in $V$ we have $\alpha =\sum_{i=1}^nf_i(\alpha)\cdot_V \alpha_i$.

**My attempt:** Let $f\in L(V,F)$. let $\alpha \in V$. Since $B=\{\alpha_1,…,\alpha_n\}$ is basis of $V$, $\exists !(x_1,…,x_n)\in F^n$ such that $\alpha =\sum_{i\in J_n}x_i\cdot_V \alpha_i$. Since $f$ is a linear map, we have $f(\alpha)$ $=f(\sum_{i\in J_n}x_i\cdot_V \alpha_i)$ $= \sum_{i\in J_n}x_i\cdot_F f(\alpha_i)$. By definition of $V^*$, $\sum_{i=1}^nf(\alpha_i)\cdot_Lf_i\in L(V,F)$. So $(\sum_{i=1}^nf(\alpha_i)\cdot_Lf_i)(\alpha)$ $= \sum_{i=1}^n(f(\alpha_i)\cdot_Lf_i)(\alpha)$ $=\sum_{i=1}^nf(\alpha_i)\cdot_Ff_i(\alpha)$. Since $f_i=\pi_i\circ h$, we have $f_i(\alpha)$ $=\pi_i(h(\alpha))$ $=\pi_i((x_1,…,x_n))=x_i$. So $\sum_{i=1}^nf(\alpha_i)\cdot_Ff_i(\alpha)$ $= \sum_{i=1}^nf(\alpha_i)\cdot_F x_i$ $= \sum_{i=1}^n x_i\cdot_F f(\alpha_i)$. Thus $f(\alpha)$ $= \sum_{i=1}^n x_i\cdot_F f(\alpha_i)$ $= (\sum_{i=1}^nf(\alpha_i)\cdot_Lf_i)(\alpha)$, $\forall \alpha \in V$. Hence $f= \sum_{i=1}^nf(\alpha_i)\cdot_Lf_i$. So $\mathrm{span}(B^*)$ $= \mathrm{span}(\{f_1,…,f_n\})=L(V,F)$. By theorem 4 corollary 2 section 2.3, $\{f_1,…,f_n\}$ is basis of $L(V,F)$.

Let $\alpha\in V$. Since $B=\{\alpha_1,…,\alpha_n\}$ is basis of $V$, $\exists !(x_1,…,x_n)\in F^n$ such that $\alpha =\sum_{i\in J_n}x_i\cdot_V \alpha_i$. By definition of map $h:V\to F^n$, we have $h(\alpha)=(x_1,…x_n)$. So $f_i(\alpha)$ $=\pi_i(h(\alpha))$ $=\pi_i((x_1,…,x_n))=x_i$, $\forall i\in J_n$. Thus $f_i(\alpha)=x_i$, $\forall i\in J_n$. Hence $\alpha =\sum_{i\in J_n}f_i(\alpha)\cdot_V \alpha_i$. **Is my proof correct?**

Comment: It's understandable from context which arithmetic you are doing. Specifying $+ _X$ and $\cdot _Y$ each time gets very tiresome to read.

Comment: @AlvinL I agree with your opinion some what, not completely. In dual space, set of all linear functional on $V$, it is okay (IMO) to make distinction for addition and scalar multiplication, because now we are “adding” and “multiplying” (scalar) functions. Which are not intuitively same as “adding” and “multiplying” real numbers.

Comment: It's not "wrong", but it is laboured. Some people might call it bad style. You are exhausting the reader with a lot of superflous details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me try to illustrate something by rewriting a part of your argument.

Take $f\in V^*$ and $\alpha\in V$. Assume $\alpha = \sum x_i\alpha _i$, where $x_i\in F$ and $\alpha_i\in B$ $^{(1)}$. By linearity of $f$ we have
$$ f(\alpha) = f\left (\sum x_i\alpha _i \right ) = \sum x_i f(\alpha _i). $$
Let $h:V\to F^n$ be the canonical isomorphism (with respect to $B$) and $\pi _i :F^n\to F$ the projection of the $i$-th coordinate. Put $f_i := \pi _ih$ for all $i$ and note that
$$ 
\begin{align*}
\left (\sum f(\alpha _i)f_i\right )(\alpha) = \sum f(\alpha _i)f_i(\alpha) &= \sum f(\alpha _i) \pi _ih(\alpha) \\
&=\sum f(\alpha _i) \pi _ih\left (\sum x_j\alpha _j\right ) \\
&=\sum f(\alpha _i)\pi _i(x_1,\ldots,x_n) \\
&=\sum x_if(\alpha _i).\quad^{(2)}
\end{align*}
$$

(1) $n$ is fixed, so $J_n$ is redundant. It is clear from context that we mean the unique linear combination with respect to the given basis $B$. It is also clear that the operation $x_i\alpha _i$ refers to the action of $F$ on $V$.

(2) Stylistically it is preferable to carry out long computations in display mode. It is easier on the eyes and also easier to follow. Notice also that there is no ambiguity regarding the multiplications involved.

> Thus $f(\alpha)$ $= \sum_{i=1}^n x_i\cdot_F f(\alpha_i)$ $= (\sum_{i=1}^nf(\alpha_i)\cdot_Lf_i)(\alpha)$, $\forall \alpha \in V$.

Correct.

> Hence $f= \sum_{i=1}^nf(\alpha_i)\cdot_Lf_i$. So $\mathrm{span}(B^*)$ $= \mathrm{span}(\{f_1,…,f_n\})=L(V,F)$.

Stay consistent with your style. You quantified the previous statement. Do so here as well. It holds that $f = \sum f(\alpha _i)f_i$ for every $f\in V^*$, thus the $f_i$ span $V^*$.

> By Corollary 2 section 2.3, $\{f_1,…,f_n\}$ is basis of $L(V,F)$

I don't see how Corollary 2 supports this statement. Corollary 2 states the following. Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space. Then

1. any collection of more than $n$ vectors is linearly dependent.
2. no collection of less than $n$ vectors spans $V$.

It is true that for finite dimensional vector spaces $V\cong V^*$, but how do you know a priori that $\dim V^* = n$? You only know that the $f_i$ span $V^*$. You should also check the $f_i$ are linearly independent.

> Let $\alpha\in V$. Since $B=\{\alpha_1,…,\alpha_n\}$ is basis of $V$, $\exists !(x_1,…,x_n)\in F^n$ such that $\alpha =\sum_{i\in J_n}x_i\cdot_V \alpha_i$. By definition of map $h:V\to F^n$, we have $h(\alpha)=(x_1,…x_n)$. So $f_i(\alpha)$ $=\pi_i(h(\alpha))$ $=\pi_i((x_1,…,x_n))=x_i$, $\forall i\in J_n$. Thus $f_i(\alpha)=x_i$, $\forall i\in J_n$. Hence $\alpha =\sum_{i\in J_n}f_i(\alpha)\cdot_V \alpha_i$.

This answers $f_i(\alpha _j) = \delta _{ij}$ (although you should make this computation explicit) and $\alpha = \sum f_i(\alpha) \alpha_i$.

> Then there is a ***unique*** dual basis $B^* = \{f_1,,…, f_n\}$ for $V^*$ such that $f_i(a_j) = \delta_{ij}$

What about this part? Again, I don't see how uniqueness (immediately) follows from 3.1 Theorem 1.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. Your proof looks nice. Theorem 4 corollary 2 section 2.3, don’t have the exact phrasing of result we are looking for, but it’s “essentially” proof of our desired result. About your last question, I have already stated existence and uniqueness of each $f_i$ by theorem 1 section 3.1.

Comment: See Hoffman’s proof. “We have shown above that there is a unique basis which is ‘dual’ to $B$“.

Comment: @user264745 Theorem 3.1 claims that for $\dim V = n$ and given any space $W$ with $\beta _1,\ldots , \beta _n\in W$ it holds that there is a unique linear map $T:V\to W$ satisfying $T\alpha _i = \beta _i$.

Comment: Yes… theorem 3.1 is general.

Comment: @user264745 Hence my comment. You should spend more time on relevant details.

Comment: @user264745 The Theorem is not in doubt. You claim the uniqueness of the dual basis follows from this Theorem. Why is that true? Theorem only mentions uniqueness of a certain linear map.

Comment: Do you really want proof? Professor Hoffman prove that claim in one sentence: We have shown above that there is a unique basis which is ‘dual’ to $B$. Claim is $\exists$…. basis of $V^*$ such that $f_i(a_j) = \delta_{ij}$. Let $\{g_1,…,g_n\}$ be basis of $V^*$ such that $g_i(a_j) = \delta_{ij}$, for each $(i,j)\in J_n \times J_n$. $f_i$ is uniquely determined by its action on target space. So $g_i=f_i$.

Answer (score 0):

**Alternative proof:** Let $f\in L(V,F)$. Let $j\in J_n$. Then $(\sum_{i\in J_n}f(\alpha_i)\cdot_L f_i)(\alpha_j)$ $=\sum_{i\in J_n}(f(\alpha_i)\cdot_Lf_i)(\alpha_j)$ $=\sum_{i\in J_n}f(\alpha_i)\cdot_F f_i(\alpha_j)$ $= \sum_{i\in J_n}f(\alpha_i)\cdot_F \delta_{ij}$ $=f(\alpha_j)$. Since $j$ was arbitrary, we have $(\sum_{i\in J_n}f(\alpha_i)\cdot_L f_i)(\alpha_j)$ $=f(\alpha_j)$, $\forall j\in J_n$. By theorem 1 section 3.1, $f=\sum_{i\in J_n}f(\alpha_i)\cdot_L f_i$.

This proof is much more efficient than showing $f(\alpha)=(\sum_{i\in J_n}f(\alpha_i)\cdot_L f_i)(\alpha)$, $\forall \alpha \in V$.

Comment: Correct. If two linear maps agree on a basis, they must be equal.