# Theorem 16 Corollary 2, Section 3.5 of Hoffman’s Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation, alternative-proof

> If $W_1$ and $W_2$ are subspaces of a finite-dimensional vector space, then $W_1=W_2$ if and only if $W_1^0=W_2^0$.

**My attempt:** Suppose $W_1=W_2$. Then clearly $W_1^0=W_2^0$. Conversely, suppose $W_1^0=W_2^0$. It’s easy to check $W_1^0,W_2^0\leq V^*$. So $\mathrm{dim}(W_1^0)= \mathrm{dim}(W_2^0)$. By theorem 16 section 3.5, $\mathrm{dim}(W_1)+ \mathrm{dim}(W_1^0)$ $= \mathrm{dim}(V)$ $= \mathrm{dim}(W_2)+ \mathrm{dim}(W_2^0)$. So $\mathrm{dim}(W_1)= \mathrm{dim}(W_2)=k$. By [theorem 16 corollary 1 section 3.5](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4500741/861687), $W_1$ $= \bigcap_{k\lt i\leq n}N_{f_i}$ $=W_2$. Hence $W_1=W_2$. **Is my proof correct?**

---

**Hoffman’s proof:** If $W_1 = W_2$,then of course $W_1^0= W_2^0$.If $W_1\neq W_2$,then one of the two subspaces contains a vector which is not in the other. Suppose there is a vector $\alpha$ which is in $W_2$ but not in $W_1$. By the previous corollaries (or the proof of Theorem 16) there is a linear functional $f$ such that $f(\beta) =0$ for all $\beta$ in $W_1$, but $f(\alpha)\neq 0$.Then $f$ is in $W_1^0$ but not in $W_2^0$ and $W_1^0\neq W_2^0$.

**Question:** I don’t understand following step of Hoffman’s proof, existence of linear functional $f$ such that $f(\beta)=0$, $\forall \beta \in W_1$, but $f(\alpha)\neq 0$.

**Edit:** My proof is wrong, reason is quite subtle.

Comment: What does the superscript $0$ mean?

Comment: Ohh! I thought it was a standard notation. Superscript $0$ denote annihilator of a set, i.e. $W^0=\{f\in V^*| f(x)=0_F\text{, }\forall x\in W\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempted proof is at best highly incomplete. The hyperplanes $N_{f_i}$ ($k+1\le i\le n$) in Corollary 1 depend upon the subspace $W$. The Corollary does *not* tell you that any two $k$-dimensional subspaces $W_1$ and $W_2$ are the intersection of the *same* $n-k$ hyperplanes in $V$. So how do we know that $W_1=W_2$?

In Hoffman and Kunze's proof, if we write $W_1=\bigcap_{k+1\le i\le n}N_{f_i}$ by Corollary 1 and $\alpha\not\in W_1$ but $\alpha\in W_2$, then there must be some $k+1\le i\le n$ with $\alpha\not\in N_{f_i}$, so $f_i(\alpha)\ne 0$ and therefore $f_i\in W_1^0$ but $f_i\not\in W_2^0$.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. Perhaps I misunderstood corollary 1. You said corollary 1 depend upon subspace $W$. I think, corollary 1 depend upon dimension of subspace $W$. $\{f_1,…,f_n\}$ is dual basis of $B$. If you carefully see proof of corollary 1, you’ll see we have only dimension of $W$ fact.

Comment: Ohhh.. wait! I think I found mistake in my proof, in proof of corollary 1 we construct $B$ (basis of $V$) using basis of subspace $W$. In this case, we have two subspace $W_1$ and $W_2$. Let $\{u_1,…,u_k\}$ and $\{v_1,…,v_k\}$ be basis of $W_1$ and $W_2$, respectively. Let $B_1$ and $B_2$ be basis of $V$ constructed from $\{u_1,…,u_k\}$ and $\{v_1,…,v_k\}$. Let $\{f_1,…,f_n\}$ and $\{g_1,…,g_n\}$ be dual basis of $B_1$ and $B_2$. So $W_1=\bigcap_{k\lt i\leq n}N_{f_i}$ and $W_2=\bigcap_{k\lt i\leq n}N_{g_i}$. Thus we can’t conclude $W_1$ and $W_2$ are equal.

Comment: For this precise reason, your explanation of Hoffman and Kunze’s proof works fine.

Comment: I saw your profile. Found out your YouTube channel. I was surprised to see you’re the same guy I’m subscribed to and had seen your category theory videos and linear algebra book review. “Hopefully I didn’t cause that”.

Comment: @user264745 Yes that's the mistake. Glad to hear you're a subscriber!