# Theorem 18, Section 3.6 of Hoffman’s Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation, dual-spaces

> If $E$ is a subset of $V^*$, then the annihilator $E^0$ is (technically) a subset
> of $V^{**}$. If we choose to identify $V$ and $V^{**}$ as in Theorem 17, then $E^0$ is a subspace of $V$, namely, the set of all $\alpha$ in $V$ such that $f(\alpha)=0$ for all $f$ in $E$. In a corollary of Theorem 16 we noted that each subspace $W$ is determined by its annihilator $W^0$. How is it determined? The answer is that $W$ is the subspace annihilated by all $f$ in $W^0$, that is, the intersection of the null spaces of all $f$’s in $W^0$. In our present notation for annihilators, the answer may be phrased very simply : $W = (W^0)^0$.
>
> **Theorem 18.** If $S$ is any subset of a finite-dimensional vector space $V$, then $(S^0)^0$ is the subspace spanned by $S$.
>
> **Proof.** Let $W$ be the subspace spanned by $S$. Clearly $W^0 = S^0$. Therefore, what we are to prove is that $W = W^{00}$. We have given one proof. Here is another. By Theorem 16, $\mathrm{dim}(W)+ \mathrm{dim}(W^0)$ $= \mathrm{dim}(V)$ and $\mathrm{dim}(W^0)+ \mathrm{dim}(W^{00})$ $=\mathrm{dim}(V^*)$. Since $\mathrm{dim}(V)$ $= \mathrm{dim}(V^*)$, we have $\mathrm{dim}(W)= \mathrm{dim}(W^{00})$. Since $W$ is a subspace of $W^{00}$, we see that $W=W^{00}$.

I find this theorem vague mainly because we’re trying show two sets are equal but they aren’t equal. Is this theorem “important”? Is it okay to skip it?

**My attempt:** Hoffman’s didn’t show lots of details in proof. I will try to fill those details. **(1)** **Claim:** $E^0=\{\alpha\in V|f(\alpha)=0\text{, }\forall f\in E\}$. **Proof:** By definition of annihilator, $E^0=\{L\in V^{**}|L(f)=0\text{, }\forall f\in E\}$. By theorem 17 section 3.6, $\forall L\in E^0$, $\exists !\alpha \in V$ such that $\phi(\alpha)=L_\alpha=L$. Thus $E^0$ $=\{L\in V^{**}|L(f)=0\text{, }\forall f\in E\}$ $= \{L_\alpha\in V^{**}|L_\alpha(f)=f(\alpha)=0\text{, }\forall f\in E\}$ $=\{\alpha \in V| f(\alpha)=0\text{, }\forall f\in E\}$. Hence $E^0= \{\alpha \in V| f(\alpha)=0\text{, }\forall f\in E\}$. **(2)** **Claim:** $W=\bigcap_{f\in W^0}N_f$. **Proof:** By [theorem 16 corollary 1 section 3.5](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4500741/861687), $W=\bigcap_{k\lt i\leq n}N_{f_i}$. By elementary set theory, $W =\bigcap_{k\lt i\leq n}N_{f_i}\supseteq \bigcap_{f\in W^0}N_f$. Conversely, $W\subseteq N_f$, $\forall f\in W^0$. Thus $W\subseteq \bigcap_{f\in W^0}N_f$. Hence $W= \bigcap_{f\in W^0}N_f$ $=\{\alpha\in V|\alpha\in N_f\text{, }\forall f\in W^0\}$ $=\{\alpha\in V|f(\alpha)=0\text{, }\forall f\in W^0\}$. So by claim $(1)$, $W$ $= \{\alpha\in V|f(\alpha)=0\text{, }\forall f\in W^0\}$ $=(W^0)^0$ $=W^{00}$. **(3)** **Claim:** $(\mathrm{span}(S))^0=S^0$. **Proof:** Let $f\in (\mathrm{span}(S))^0$. Then $f(x)=0_F$, $\forall x\in \mathrm{span}(S)$. Since $S\subseteq \mathrm{span}(S)$, we have $f(x)=0_F$, $\forall x\in S$. Thus $f\in S^0$. Hence $(\mathrm{span}(S))^0\subseteq S^0$. Conversely suppose $f\in S^0$. Then $f(x)=0_F$, $\forall x\in S$. let $v\in \mathrm{span}(S)$. So $v=\sum_{i\in J_n}a_i\cdot u_i$, where $n\in \Bbb{N}$, $a_i\in F$, $u_i\in S$. Since $f$ is a linear map, precisely $f\in V^*$$=L(V,F)$, we have $f(v)$ $=f(\sum_{i\in J_n}a_i\cdot u_i)$ $= \sum_{i\in J_n}a_i\cdot f(u_i)$ $= \sum_{i\in J_n}a_i\cdot 0_F$ $=0_F$. Since $v$ was arbitrary, $f(v)=0_F$, $\forall v\in \mathrm{span}(S)$. Thus $f\in (\mathrm{span}(S))^0$. Hence $S^0\subseteq (\mathrm{span}(S))^0$. So $S^0= (\mathrm{span}(S))^0$. Which implies $(S^0)^0$ $= ((\mathrm{span}(S))^0)^0$ $=S^{00}$ $= (\mathrm{span}(S))^{00}$ $=\mathrm{span}(S)$. Thus $S^{00}=\mathrm{span}(S)$. **Is my proofs correct?**

**Question:** “Since $W$ is a subspace of $W^{00}$….”. How $W$ is a subspace of $W^{00}$? It seems absurd!

Comment: Do you understand what they mean when they say we can identify $V$ and $V^{**}$? It means each vector $\alpha\in V$ can be viewed as a linear function on $V^*$, where the action of $\alpha$ on $f\in V^*$ is just $f(\alpha)$. With this understanding, do you see why $W$ is a subspace of $W^{00}$?

Comment: @blargoner Imo, saying $W\subseteq W^{00}$ makes more sense.  By claim $(1)$, $W^{00}=\{\alpha\in V|f(\alpha)=0\text{, }\forall f\in W^0\}$. Let $\alpha \in W$. Then $f(\alpha)=0$, $\forall f \in W^0$. Thus $\alpha \in W_{00}$. Yes I do kind of understand identify $V$ and $V^{00}$. Why don’t we just write $W=\phi^{-1}(W^{00})$? There would be no ambiguity.

Comment: I often struggle with this in functional analysis as well, but it's a common practice. Things like denoting the dual of $\ell^p$ by $\ell^q$, where $p^{-1} + q^{-1} = 1$, is a similar abuse of notation: while $\ell^q$ is naturally isomorphic to $(\ell^p)^*$, it contains sequences, not functionals. Similar identifications are everywhere, and are convention. Attempts to make things clearer by removing ambiguity can often have the opposite of the intended effect: adding the extra symbols will tend to confuse an experienced reader, rather than help them.

Comment: @TheoBendit It is nice to hear I’m not the only struggling with notation. After reading your comment I feel much more confident.